# dependency-check Maven Plugin 'two-phases' configuration

Tags: maven-plugin, verify, maven-dependency-check-plugin

I'm having maven project using dependency-check Maven Plugin [https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/plugin-info.html%5C](dependency-check-maven)

The goal is to be able to run first dependency scan to get report as a part of verify stage or running plugin goal (aggregate) separately.

Then build maven site to include dependencies scan report into site.

On 'first' stage running plugin using aggregate goal directly.

`mvn org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:check -Dformats=ALL`

or as part of verify stage

```
  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
          <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
          <version>8.4.3</version>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>aggregate</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
```

`mvn verify -Dformats=ALL`

This produces target/dependency-check-report.(xml,json,html.. all others)

Configure dependency-check plugin to be run on site stage

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>aggregate</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Running `mvn site` creates target/site/dependency-check-report.html and includes report into generated site

The issue is actually is that dependencies in this case are analyzed twice.
If I run for 'site' stage

`mvn site -Ddependency-check.skip=false`

then reporting section is completely skipped and dependencies check report is not included into site 'Project Reports'.
Is there any way to configure/run dependency-check maven plugin (goals) to consume for site report data, created on previous stage and include dependency-check:aggregate into site 'Project Reports' without running actual analysis again?